# Minimize Borderless Form

Tags: c#, forms

When I set the WindowState to Minimized, it's change to Maximized automatically.

```
private void btnMinimizeForm_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}
```

I tried to re-add the System.Windows.Forms referense and rebuild the project but its didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you hiding and showing the form again? Is `this` referring to the same form?

Comment: No. I just click in the btnMinimizeForm. "this" is refering the same form.

Comment: Have yu harcoded form hight and width anywhere?

Comment: Dear vivek nuna. Thank you for try to help me. I solved the problem. Was an error in form_move event on calculeta the form position in the Y axis.